# Only some functions work with the Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am experimenting with the Twitter API and I'm finding a bit confusing that my code works with only some the functions listed in the API documentacion https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

For example:

I can succesfully get the list of available places with this code:

```
from twitter import *
from datetime import datetime

OAUTH_TOKEN = 'my token'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'my secret token'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'my key'
CONSUMER_SECRET ='my secret key'

t = Twitter( auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
        CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET) )

trends1 = t.trends.available()
print trends1
```

However, if I use the place() function, instead of available() it doesn't work:

```
from twitter import *
from datetime import datetime

OAUTH_TOKEN = 'my token'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'my secret token'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'my key'
CONSUMER_SECRET ='my secret key'

t = Twitter( auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
        CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET) )

trends1 = t.trends.place(1)
print trends1
```

The code is the same except that I am using place() instead of available().

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: What exact library is this? There is, I believe, more than one Python Twitter library that is imported as `import twitter`.

Comment: I suspect you are using [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter) as the signature of `Twitter()` matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use keyword arguments when calling:

```
trends1 = t.trends.place(_id=1)
```

The `twitter.TwitterCall()` object that proxies the API request does not know how to translate positional arguments to URL parameters; it carries no mapping from *argument at position 0* to *parameter `id` in the query*.

The `id` keyword, however, is special; the `twitter` library assumes that to be part of the URL; `_id` should be used when the API call requires a `id=..` query parameter instead.

The PyPI page doesn't render the readme very well; you may want to refer to the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) instead as the examples are more readable there. That page gives, among others, the following example:

> ```
> # to pass in the GET/POST parameter `id` you need to use `_id`
> t.statuses.oembed(_id=1234567890)
> ```

For completeness sake, the counter example is when to use `id`; the API URL [`geo/id/:place_id`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/id/%3Aplace_id) becomes:

```
t.geo.id(id='df51dec6f4ee2b2c')  # pass in `id` to extend the URL
t.geo.id.df51dec6f4ee2b2c()      # build the URL as an attribute instead
```

Yes, that's two forms that both work, but not all valid id values are valid Python attribute names.